# Что означает появляющийся тег <img> в консоли инструментов Developer Tools браузера Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

В коде никаких img не выводится.

Comment: Если html-файл просто перетащить в браузер, то <img> в консоли не появляется, кстати, только когда через сервер запускаешь. Сейчас это выяснила. Использую OpenServer. Как это может быть связано?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Появляющийся тег `<img>` в консоли инструментов Developer Tools при просмотре пустой страницы означает что страница не такая уж и пустая.

Comment: Действительно, перепроверила, в пустых документах он отсутствует. Так что сам по себе он значит, каково его назначение кроме как индикации присутствия кода?

Comment: @Anomnimel Картинка не 1х1px случайно?

Comment: @Khipster тоже про 1x1 image_tag подумал для статистики

Comment: @Khipster О чем речь? Никакие картинки я не подключала. Вот скрин того, что я имею ввиду. http://imgdepo.com/id/i9870373

Comment: @Anomnimel Это же консоль, а не разметка :/

Comment: @Khipster Я же и спросила про консоль =_=

Comment: @Anomnimel По видимому при загрузке вашей "пустой" странички загружается JS-код который и выводит в консоль элемент <img>, который судя по всему тоже существует.

Comment: @Khipster JS не подключала, пруф: http://imgdepo.com/id/i9870375 Давно заметила это <img> в консоли, специально вот выясняю, что это такое и всегда ли так было

Comment: @Anomnimel VM это Virtual Machine, т.е. JS движок браузера.

Comment: @Khipster Тогда интересно, почему такое происходит только при запуске с локального сервера

Comment: @Anomnimel Расширения выключите, ADBLOCK и т.д.

Comment: @Khipster Спасибо, это правда оказалось взаимосвязано. Из всех расширений это одно для скачивания музыки с контакта.. Что оно там делает с VM, это тайна, покрытая мраком, видимо О_о